# How to set a 'code behind' property via jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to set the value of a property inside the page class using jQuery? I know it's possible to get the value in jQuery as long as the property is public but can't seem to set the value.

This is the property in the code behind.

```
Private inventory_item_id As String = ""

Public Property InventoryItemId() As String
    Get
        Return inventory_item_id
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        inventory_item_id = value
    End Set
End Property
```

`<%=Me.InventoryItemId %> = 'some value';` isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, you should know that `<%=Me.InventoryItemId %>` substitutes the actual value when the page is rendered (view source on the page in your browser you will see the id, say 1234, not a reference to the property). That being said, you could set the value of a hidden field on the client side which you could then read during postback and use to set your property. Note that the answer "no" is technically correct - the property no longer exists once the page has been rendered - but there is nothing stopping you from setting it again during the postback.

In fact, your could make your property directly tied to a hidden field:

```
Public Property InventoryItemId() As String
    Get
        Return hdnInventoryItemId.Value
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        hdnInventoryItemId.Value = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Which assumes that you have the following hidden field defined:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnInventoryItemId" runat="server"/>
```

Finally, your jQuery could set the field with the following syntax (but this is just one of many, many ways it could be set):

```
$('<%= hdnInventoryItemId.ClientID %>').val('some value');
```

Comment: This is how I am doing it now, with the use of a hidden field.  I was hoping there was a way to do an inline <%= %> call to set it.  I can always call a webservice to do it using .ajax but that really isn't worth the effort.  I will stick with using the hidden field as I have been.  Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: @Nathan Setting a property via ajax probably would not do anything useful - the property would not be persisted after the ajax call so unless you were doing something with it immediately (saving to a database, processing and returning something to the client, etc) the effort would be wasted.

Comment: @Nathan, setting the property via ajax has *no meaning* since the property does not exist anymore.  When you request a web form page, an instance of the code behind is created, it's life cycle is run, the page is rendered, then poof, the class instance is dead.  Forever.  Incidentally, that's also why ajax calls can only call static methods in the code behind class, and not instance methods.  David's answer is outstanding, and the best you're going to be able to do.

Answer (score 5):

### No

That code behind value only exists when the page is loading, and going through its page life-cycle. Now, while the page is loading, you can certainly drop the value into a script, by doing something like

`var valueFromServer = <% Me.InventoryItemId %>;`

But, once the page is loaded, you can't go back and change that property, *because it no longer exists*

Comment: The definitive "no" made me smile.

Answer (score 0):

How do you plan to retrieve the new value after it's been updated by JS/JQ? If you're performing some sort of client-side recalculation and then submitting the value back to the server, you could create a hidden field like that stores your property's value.

Then, when users submit your page (or post-back, whatever), you can check the value of that hidden field and update your property appropriately.